# How to render an Image by URL from Axios.get()

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I have problems and need help with rendering an image in React. The problem is that this image is stored locally, and the URL to this image is retrieved from database with Axios.get() along with some other data. All data is showing up fine, but cannot render that image.

```js
class Lesson extends Component {
        state = {
 lesson: null
        };

componentDidMount() {
        Axios.get("https://localhost:44372/api/Lesson/lesson/" +
            this.props.location.pathname.substring(
                this.props.location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
        ).then(response => {   
 console.log("API Response", response);
 const newLesson = response.data;
 this.setState({
     lesson: newLesson,
            });
        });
}

    render() {
        return (<div>
     <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>{this.state.lesson.title}</h2>
     <p>{this.state.lesson.text}</p>
     <p>{this.state.lesson.field1}</p>

     <img src={this.state.lesson.img}         //<-----here
         alt="none"
      style={{
      verticalAlign: "middle",
      display: "block",
      margin: "auto",
      marginLeft: "auto",
      marginRight: "auto"
         }}
     />

    <div>);
```

In this way that image does not show up.

Error that I encounter is: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/Project/FrontEnd/platform/src/images/python_img.PNG

The only way that I can get that img is to insert like this manually, but this is not what I want:

```js
<img src={require("D:\\Project\\FrontEnd\\platform\\src\\images\\python_img.PNG")}
```

I thought that the problem is in componentDidMount(), as I was getting an undefined value at start, but later I just provided the same path from parent page (just to check) and the problem is the same.

I am doing something wrong...

Is a way to provide as image source a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the images itself is bundled in your react app, then its not going to work like you expect.

*require()* only accepts static

Things you can do

1.Render conditionally

```
const images = {
   image1: require('./image1.jpg'),
   image2: require('./image2.jpg'),
};
```

Then in your app

```
    <img src={this.state.lesson.img === 'something_unique' ? images.image1 : images.image2}         //<-----here
        alt="none"
        style={{
        verticalAlign: "middle",
        display: "block",
        margin: "auto",
        marginLeft: "auto",
        marginRight: "auto"
        }}
    />
```

2.Or if your using a bundler, you can get the public URL and append it.

```
<img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + this.state.lesson.img} />
```

Comment: Following your advice just moved all images in public folder, then rendering using your line, and everything works fine. Thank you.
<img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + this.state.lesson.img} />